# In landing, how much of a Falcon 9 First stage's velocity is lost to air resistance and how much to retropropulsion?

Tags: falcon-9, resistance

Thinking about [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33078/why-cant-spacex-starship-perform-the-same-landing-procedure-as-the-falcon-9-doe) I was led to wonder to what extent retropropulsion is used to kill the F9 first stage's full velocity and to what extent it is used simply for course control and landing, with air resistance doing the rest of the work.

Comment: It's more like loss of delta-v than loss of velocity *per se* (pretending I know how to use latin makes me feel smart for about 3 seconds)

Comment: What? Of course it’s loss of velocity.

Comment: I guess uhoh was thinking about launch drag losses, rather than landing drag gains

Comment: @RussellBorogove I don't like partitioning something called "lost velocity" in a potential field with additional losses and variable mass. Delta-v is an understood concept that sounds similar but has an accepted methodology associated with it. Post your quantitative answer and show us how the pros do it? I started, using CRS-16 but ran out of steam and coffee [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTtVH.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huz2H.png) from flightclub.io I'll give a bounty to a convincing, quantitative answer that uses mathematics, but down vote a verbal handy-wavy "space-words" answer.